# How to install cmake-gui through conda-forge?

Tags: c++, cmake, anaconda

I like the idea of using conda-forge to install cmake since it keeps it up to date and I'm familiar with updating packages in conda.
I installed "conda install cmake" successfully, but it doesn't look like it installed cmake-gui along with it. Is there anyway to do that? I've tried "conda install cmake[gui]" and "conda install cmake-qt-gui" unsuccessfully.

I'm using Windows